# How to have a log in array

Tags: c#, arrays

i am trying to make this so instead of having only one user it can hold many.

i got it to work like the code below. but i wanted it instead of just username1 and password1 i want it to have an array of usernames and passwords.

i just don't know how to have it read an array.

an example of what i think it would be is like a 2,2 array then if 1,1 and 1,2 match then pass if not fail.

i also would like to know how i could make it add a username and password from array and to delete one.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username1 = "chris";
    string password1 = "VETS";

    if (this.username.Text == username1 && this.password.Text == password1)
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
}
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: You might just want to start reading [the documentation for arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class

```
public class User
{

    public string UserName{get; set;}
    public string Password{get; set;}

    public User(string name, string pw)
    {
        this.UserName = name;
        this.Password = pw;
    }
}
```

...

```
User[] userArray = new User[5];

for(int i=0; i<userArray.Length; i++)
{
    userArray[i] = new User("chris", "VETS");
}
```

I feel like I'm required to warn you against spinning your own username/password scheme.  It will probably be less secure than built-in ones.

Comment: Please dont have a constructor with parameters that are public. Make them a private set or remove them!